# Regex to replace second occurrence of a character

Tags: regex, replace

I have some data in the following format:

**MM:ss:mmm** where `MM is minutes`, `ss is seconds` and `mmm is 3 digit milliseconds`, like:

```
05:23:236
```

I'm trying to replace the second occurrence of the colon with a dot:

```
05:23.236
```

I'd like to use a `regex` pattern to do a replace in an editor like Notepad++, I came up with
this regex to match my expression:

```
 \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,3}
```

But now how can I get only the `second occurrence of colon` so I can replace it with `dot`?

**EDIT:** Notice that the data I'm working with could come with 1-2 digit minute, 1-2 digit second and 1-3 digit millisecond

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
:(\d{1,3})$
```

to replace with:

```
.$1
```

What above is doing is selecting the last `:` which is followed by milliseconds by 1-3 digits.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/bL7bE6)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  string pattern =  @":(?=\d{3})";
  string input = "your string";
  string replacement = ".";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Answer (score 2):

your regex was good, you just have to do group and then replace them by calling them again:

selection:

```
(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}):(\d{1,3})
```

replace:

```
$1\.$2
```

Answer (score 1):

Find: `:(\d{1,3})$`

Replace with: `.\1` or `.$1` depending on your regex flavour